# Zabbix trigger configuration

Tags: zabbix

My template is a custom template Template Social-php, which has one item with one trigger and one key proc.num[php] , with type Zabbix agent (active)
My trigger is   {Template Social -Proc:proc.num[php].last(0)}<2

I am using 2 because my tests are below:

`proc.num[php] returns the correct value`

root@node22:~# zabbix_agentd -t proc.num[php]
proc.num[php]                                 [u|2]

On the server also returns 2, so the trigger I should be setting is less than 2 then alert

`zabbix_get -s node22-k proc.num[php]
2`

My issue is that there are alerts on the front page of zabbix that the service php isnt running even after I enter the new trigger and no matter what I change it to, it wont go away unless I disable it.

I also tested the trigger syntax in the expression constructor but not getting the value I want, so there is a disconnect somewhere.

Comment: Please, edit your question and provide error message you are getting related to this trigger.

Comment: Andrew, your problem requires some debug actions. It is not easy to answer your question based on what you have provided so far. You should edit your question and add at least the error message you are getting. Ideally you should provide information about **items**, **hosts**, **templates** and **actions** configuration of Zabbix (relevant for your problem).

Comment: Sorry about that, I have made the corrections

Answer (score 0):

You are using a different item key in your Zabbix configuration and your `zabbix_get` request - notice the second parameter being set to `root`. That adds extra filtering, and does not match your running `php` processes.

Comment: Sorry, both the zabbix_get command and the trigger command should work, but they are the same .

My troubleshooting steps are 
[code]
I have tried different comparative methods , last() , diff() , minimum 2 minutes

As I said above I ran the zabbix_get command on the server against different nodes and got the correct value 2

I also ran ps fu root and saw the two php processes running , and if I stopped the php script, and run the zabbix_get commannd against the node I get 0 which is correct
[/code]

Comment: Take a look at your trigger expression, which references the item key: `{Template Social -Proc:proc.num[php,root].max(2m)}<2`. Notice how the referenced key is `proc.num[php,root]`, not `proc.num[php]` that you tested with `zabbix_get`.

Comment: thank you, I made the change but nothing works. Also with zabbix_get both [php,root] and [php] as key works

Comment: "nothing works" is a bit vague :) Maybe you can summarise the best config you have in place.